# Why AWS Beanstalk service is using S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, hosting

I've launched an application in AWS -> Beanstalk using pre-installed server template.

In the process of Beanstalk installation I see it is creating S3 bucket. I'm pretty sure that I didn't select any option to use S3 bucket. If S3 bucket is needed for the Beanstalk application, can you tell me how it works together and what is the purpose? Can I prevent using S3 with Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This S3 bucket is indeed automatically created by Elastic Beanstalk for your new application.

It is used to store some environment files, and more important, zipped builds of your app (each one being a different version). The Beanstalk deployment script simply downloads the .zip from the bucket to the EBS volume.

It looks like there is no option on AWS to change this.

*By the way, why don't you want to use S3?*

Comment: Because in the billing section it says, that I've exceed sending request to S3 and it's being charged, the request are sent by Beanstalk. If I'm right then S3 play no role running application via Beanstalk, and S3 just storing .zip files uploaded by Beanstalk?